# Getting Longitude and Latitude from the GpsMyLocationProvider (OSMdroid)

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, android-gps

I am programming a navigation app with OSMdroid.

How do I extract latitute and longitude from the GpsMyLocationProvider into a Geopoint, so I can center the map on it?

`this.mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(this),map);
        this.mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();`

I tried this. But it just makes the app crash, as soon as I press the button for this method:
`mapController.setCenter((IGeoPoint) this.mLocationOverlay);`

Comment: What is the error you get when the app crashes? Is mapController null?

Comment: @jimmycarr When I debug, at the last line the map controller is "MapController@4177"

Comment: Do you see an error in the console? What type of exception do you get?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay cannot be cast to org.osmdroid.api.IGeoPoint

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are casting `MyLocationNewOverlay` to a `IGeoPoint` but it doesn't implement the interface `IGeoPoint`, so you will be getting a ClassCastException. Make sure you pass in a valid `IGeoPoint` to `setCenter()`.

Comment: Okay, so first I need to create a proper Geopoint with `GeoPoint myLocation = new GeoPoint(longitude, latitude)`? The problem is, that I have no idea, how to get the longitude and the latitude from the GpsMyLocationProvider.

Comment: You can call `.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude()` on the location provider

Comment: Android Studio tells me: Non-static method "getLastKnowLocation()" cannot be referenced from a static context. Sorry I am new to Java.

Comment: You have to call that method on the instance of GpsMyLocationProvider that you created. In your case you can do `this.mLocationOverlay.getMyLocationProvider().getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude()`

Comment: This is my code now: `double latitude = this.mLocationOverlay.getMyLocationProvider().getLastKnownLo‌​cation().getLatitude‌​();` Android Studio tells me: "Cannot resolve method getLastKnownLocation()"

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with that. Are you using the latest version of OSMDroid? I can see the method signature here so it should be allowed: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/mylocation/IMyLocationProvider.java

Comment: The error is gone now. I dont even know why. But now my app crashes as soon as I get that line.

Comment: I have put the lines in the oncreate method of my mainactivity

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference